# Accessing array indices in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I am new to React and Javascript as a whole. I am simply trying to access array indices after a fetch. I can log a specific index after a file update, but when I refresh the page, I get an 'Undefined' error. I feel as if I am doing something wrong with my state, but I don't know enough about React to debug this. if I attempt to access " users[0].name", I get the "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
(anonymous function).

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { Container, Card, Divider, Typography } from "@mui/material";

const RestData = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container>
      {data.map((users) => {
        return (
          <Card
            data={data}
            key={users.id}
            sx={{ width: "300px", mt: 2, background: "#ff9800" }}
          >
            <Typography variant="h6" color="seagreen">
              {users.name}
            </Typography>
            <Divider />
            {users.email}
            <Divider />
            {users.company.name}
            <Divider />
            {users.phone}
            <Divider />
            {users.website}
            <Divider />
          </Card>
        );
      })}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default RestData;
```

Comment: What is the Undefined error? Could you post the whole message?

Comment: For what would you like to use the indices? Display it as an id?

Comment: Agree here with @theJuls could you edit the post and add the underfined error message

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
(anonymous function)

Comment: I have edited the post with the specific error an condition.

Comment: When you initialize the `users` state to `[]`, trying to access users[0].name will result in the error you describe. You need to make sure you're not trying to access the array until your data has been fetched. You could check to see if users[0] exists before accessing it, or you could try implementing a [loading state](https://www.mariokandut.com/how-to-handle-errors-and-data-loading-state-with-react-hooks/)

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't see this occurring in the code you posted, you are getting that particular error because you are trying to access `.name` when the object
being accessed is undefined.

I presume you are trying to do something like `data[0].name`.

The issue is, your `data` array starts empty, so if you try to access any index of an empty array, it will be `undefined`, you will get that error.

The solution is to make sure the `data` array already has it's elements in before you access an index of it.

Now, there are many ways to do this. Because it doesn't seem to be a part of your code, it is hard to tell you the best way. But here is a couple:

1- Do an if check before attempting to access the property:

```js
if (data[0]) {
  console.log(data[0].name)
  // do stuff
}
```

2- Check if the property exists first using the `&&` operator:
For this case, the attempt to access the `name` is only done if `data[0]` is truthy.

```js
console.log(data[0] && data[0].name)
```

3- Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). This is the better one imo, since it allows you to skip the if and will only attempt to access a property if it is not `undefined`.

```js
console.log(data[0]?.name)
```

So now to put this in practice, here is a sample app:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data));
  }, []);

  console.log("data", data);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h3>Example by accessing the index directly with Optional Chaining:</h3>
        <p>{data[0] && data[0].name}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <h3>Example with the map</h3>
      {(data).map((d) => {
        return <p>{d.name}</p>;
      })}
      
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're fetching the data at rendering time you don't have `users[0].name`, so what I would suggest is to use the conditional operator `?`. 
So you have something like this

```js
data[0]?.name
```

What happens in this case is that typescript try to access the property `name` at the given index, if the property is `undefined` returns null otherwise returns the value.

I've also made a quick [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-http-wkjz2?file=/src/App.js) for demonstration.